# Doctrine with Load balancer

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm searching for help because I've been turning into circle without solution to my problem with php and Doctrine. I don't use Synfony, only Doctrine.

Here's my problem:

I open a transaction like this :

```
$connection = $entityManager->getConnection();
$connection->beginTransaction();
```

Then I do a

```
try {
    - SELECT one entity with some criteria (all criteria combined defined a secondary unique key). If no row is found, I create a new entry, otherwise, I save the unique Id.

    ... The rest of the treatment
// Commit the transaction
    $connection->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Rollback the transaction
    $connection->rollBack();

    $entityManager->clear();
    $entityManager->close();
}
```

During my tests with WAMP, everything works fine. But when I delivered in production environment, here comes the trouble!

My prod server (professional) is configured with a load balancer and 3 backends. When I tried to do a mass test (198 requests in one shot), I have, in results, several times the same row created in my first table.
I know this comes from the commit is done at the end of the transaction (mandatory to have the possibility to do a rollback on the whole transaction) and that the 3 backends treat requests in parallel.
The only solution I found is to put manually a LOCK on table to let the first request to be treated and the row created in the table, but I think this solution is quite dirty.

I tried to use Doctrine LOCK (pessimistic) but you can't lock a row with a findBy and obviously not a row that is not created yet.
I also tried to put a unique index on my criteria, mais when I have the DUPLICATE KEY error thrown, the Entity Manager is closed.

Does anyone have a clue ? Because my unnumerous search on Google didn't help me to solve this.
Sorry, I can't post more code because it is professional business.

Thanks for your help.